# Why am I having 4 different keys when Insert a key frame and how I can disable it to just 1 on a line?

Tags: keyframes

[image]

I'm having 4 different keys here which should not be. I should have just one.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Click on that ">" here in your timeline:

[image]

and it will open like this and will show you, what you keyframed:

[image]

you can select one:

[image]

then press "X" to delete.

Whenever you press "I" in the viewport, Blender asks you what you want to keyframe:

[image]

so e.g. you choose "location", it will create 3 keyframes, one for each axis.

[image]

Each point does NOT mean it is really a keyframe. Blender does show for the "summary" entries like "Cube" a keyframe point too, to just show "hey, there are some keyframes here, please open hierarchy to see them"

So the "real" keyframes are in the list only those, where no arrow is on the left side.

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: if my answer helped you, please click on the checkmark left of my answer. Thank you.